# Convert XML response to array in PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap

I am getting xml back from an API request and want to know how to turn only the `<soap:Body>` to `</soap:Body>` section of it into an array in PHP. I haven't seen any simple or logical ways to do this in my searching.

Any information that would point me in the correct direction would be great!

Thanks in advance.

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soap:Header>
    <wsa:Action>http://www.urlhere.com/</wsa:Action>
    <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</wsa:MessageID>
    <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</wsa:RelatesTo>
    <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
    <wsse:Security>
      <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-4cf61b60-957a-454a-a828-90bd373301af">
        <wsu:Created>2001-01-01T00:00:00Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires>2001-01-01T00:00:00Z</wsu:Expires>
      </wsu:Timestamp>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <blah xmlns="http://www.urlhere.com/schema">
      <blahblah>
        <blahblahblah>0</blahblahblah>
      </blahblah>
    </blah>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I would like this as a result

```
array('body'=>array('blah'=>array('blahblah'=>array('blahblahblah'=>0))))
```

Comment: $array=json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($xmlstring)),true); print_r($array); Should help

Comment: I'd say you should be using the PHP Soap Client for that API

Comment: @user574632 that gives me a blank array back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to use SimpleXML http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

You could craft an xpath to match on the namespaced element.

```
$simple = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$result = $simple->xpath('//soap:Body');
echo $result[0]->blah->blahblah->blahblahblah;
```

I'm not going to present the "array" solution as complex XML structures require different kinds of processing/iteration, all covered by the simpleXML documentation.

---

Addition: Adding a better example of namespace consumption

```
$simple = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$simple->registerXPathNamespace('foo','http://www.urlhere.com/schema');
$result = $simple->xpath('//foo:blah');
echo $result[0]->blahblah->blahblahblah;
```

Comment: These are going to be dynamic complex XML responses. Each containing different xml tags.